# When ios in app purchases becomes available for querying

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have added in app purchases to my ios app which was not yet submitted for review. In 'in app purchases' section the only warnin is : "Your first In-App Purchases must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section on Details and click Submit." And has ready to submit status. I also added in app purchase in version app section. Will i be able to fetch it in code?

Comment: When using an API for the first time, your starting point should be it's official guide. [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html)